# Ember how to just add additional named outlets to view without disturbing the normal behaviour

Tags: view, ember.js, outlet

I'm trying to render in my index page three additional `outlet`'s, everything works fine, except that once I set up at least one outlet, the normal behaviour get interrupted. To be more clear here is what I'm doing

My `IndexRoute` route

```
renderTemplate: function() {
    this._super();
    this.render('header', { into: 'index', outlet: 'header' });
    this.render('sidebar', { into: 'index', outlet: 'sidebar' });
    this.render('right_side', { into: 'index', outlet: 'right_side' });
}
```

Now my routes are mapped so `index` is a resource and contains all other routes inside. My view contains all `outlet`'s setted to render and one unnamed outlet, which causes a problems.

If I do not explicitly name what to render and where in `IndexRoute`, things work fine, I get my template rendered in my unnamed outlet, links work fine and unnamed outlet get the right content, but once I set up any named outlet, the unnamed outlet stops getting any content, though I'm calling `_super()`.

So my question is how can I set up additional named outlets without disturbing normal work of unnamed outlet in the same `resource`?

**Update**

example
http://jsfiddle.net/drulia/jM6js/

Comment: Could you put together a JSFiddle for this please?

Comment: updated question with fiddle

Comment: Don't your `{{outlet}}`s all need to be in your application template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the issue is with multiple `outlets`, but I got it to work using `partial` helper.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
 {{#linkTo index/foo}}Go to Foo{{/linkTo}} <br>
 {{#linkTo index/bar}}Go to Bar{{/linkTo}} <hr>
 text inside index template
 <hr>
 {{outlet}}
 {{render "sidebar"}}
</script>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alex_navasardyan/u422F/).

**Update**

jsfiddle was updated to use `{{render}}` helper instead of `{{partial}}`.

If you're using `{{partial}}` helper, it will use existing context. If you need to reuse models/controllers, you're better of using `{{render}}` because it creates a new view/controller/template context for you. Then you might use `modelFor` or `controllerFor` hooks.

Comment: yeah, but in this case sidebar will have to share the contoller with 'index', and I have three additional `outlet`'s which would overwhelm my controller and I'm not sure as well how to set up more than one  model for controller. Or is there a way to set up separate controllers for `partial`'s views?

Comment: @Giedrius you might better off using `{{render}}` instead of `{{partial}}` then. `{{render}}` will give you a 'view/controller/template' context of its own.

Comment: Thanks, `{{render}}` is exactly what I needed, I should to know that.